# EclipseLink "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named ..." exception

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to create a simple Java app, using JPA to communicate with a MySQL database, that allows me to insert new rows into the tables found in the database, retrieve the data inside them, etc. But when I try running it, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named default
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at com.lab9.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

I know this question has already been asked a few times on here, but none of the older threads have been of any help to me. Usually, people seem to get this exception because they have their `persistence.xml` file in the wrong directory, or because they forgot to specify a `<provider>` in said file, neither of which is the case for me. This is what my project structure looks like in IntelliJ:

[image]

As you can see, I have `persistence.xml` in `src/main/resources/META-INF`, where it's supposed to be. Inside this file, I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <class>com.lab9.Continent</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cities"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And finally, in my `pom.xml` file, I added these dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.28</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've tried pretty much everything: moving files around, adding and deleting dependencies, re-writing the whole program from scratch, yet nothing seems to work.

Comment: My experiences have me believe this error is commonly because of class paths. Where is the persistence.xml file itself: are you able to load it in your java app's main method? Are you able to load the org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider class in it (new PersistenceProvider()) ? https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging shows how to turn on logging, but only helps if EclipseLink is trying to load the file and throwing an error doing so - you might have to use a debugger to see where and what the Persistence class is loading and if it gets that far.

Comment: Hi @0410 Could you please help as I also got that error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You use a latest version of persistence xml based on jakarta xsd (3.0) but you use javax.persistence to connect to your database.

You juste have to use :
org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider

```
<property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="Driver ..."/>
<property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:..."/>
<property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
<property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="psw"/>
```

and include the folloin artifacte in you'r pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
 </dependency>

-- Or
  


 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core-jakarta</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.9.Final</version>
 </dependency>
```