# How to define a persistenceprovider for a getEntityManager method?

Tags: java, persistence, dao, entitymanager, entitymanagerfactory

I am trying implement a template for my Model classes in my java/servlet project, with methods for create tables, insert, update, delete and select data. the start point for all this methods is this method `protected EntityManager getEntityManager()` where I define where the sqlite database is located and other preferences.

But when this method is executed, the error `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named default` happens. My current implementation for this method is:

```
public abstract class Dao<E extends Model> {
    private Class<E> classe;

    public Dao(Class<E> classe) {
        this.classe = classe;
        if(!exists()) create();
    }

protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    String url = getClass().getResource("/data.db").toString();
    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.provider", "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "org.sqlite.JDBC");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:sqlite:"+url);
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default", properties);
    return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}

    ...
}
```

anyone knows how to solve this, without have to include an external library like hibernate or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are facing:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named default
```

is raised when you are trying creating the `EntityManagerFactory` in this line of code:

```java
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default", properties);
```

Under the hood, this method will invoke the configured [`PersistenceProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider.html) but according to the error either no one is configured or there is some type of misconfiguration.

A `PersistenceProvider` is configured when defining your application JPA persistence unit. For this purpose you need to define an appropriate `persistence.xml` file (please, consider read for example [this related article of Vlad Mihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persistence-xml/)).

The content of this file will depend on the actual JPA implementation library that you are using, although it will be the same in a great extend.

For example, consider review the configuration provided for Hibernate in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/etissieres/5796622):

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="sample">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>org.sample.entities.Entity</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite::memory:" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

For EclipseLink, as in your example, I came across [this excellent example](https://github.com/rgarciacarmona/JPA-Demo/blob/master/src/META-INF/persistence.xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
 
    <!-- Persistence Provider -->
    <!-- RESOURCE-LOCAL: Application-managed transactions -->
    <!-- JTA: Container-managed transactions -->
    <persistence-unit name="company-provider" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
 
        <!-- Entity Class -->
        <class>sample.db.pojos.Employee</class>
        <class>sample.db.pojos.Department</class>
        <class>sample.db.pojos.Report</class>
 
        <properties>    
            <!-- Connection properties -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:./db/company.db" />
            <!-- Fill if we need user and password -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            
            <!-- Controls logging level -->
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
            <!-- <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL" /> -->

            <!-- JPA doesn't create the schema -->
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <!-- JPA destroys and recreates the schema -->
            <!-- <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" /> -->
        </properties>
 
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Please, note that in any case the persistence unit name should be the one you configured, `default`:

```
persistence-unit name="default"
```

The `persistence.xml` usually must be defined in the `META-INF` directory, i.e., if you are using Maven standard layout, in `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`.

With this configuration in place, you can create the `EntityManagerFactory` manually with the following code:

```java
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
```

Regarding your comments, please, note that unless you are using some type of dependency injection mechanism - Spring, CDI - you will not be able to use the `@PersistenceUnit` annotation (please, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381724/persistenceunit-annotation-wont-create-an-entitymanagefactory-emf-null) related SO question): as stated, you need to create the `EntityManagerFactory` manually as described above.

One of the above mentioned repositories provides a more [complete example](https://github.com/rgarciacarmona/JPA-Demo/blob/master/src/sample/db/jpa/FullJPAExample.java).

You need to include the required dependencies, Hibernate or EcliseLink, in your project; I am aware that you mentioned if anybody knows how to do that without those libraries but, and I hope to be wrong, I think that the task of implementing a custom `PersistenceProvider` could be cornerstone. Please, take into account that you will need to implement, among other things, the `EntityManager` itself, model all the transitions between the different persistent states of the entity, etc. Please, prefer instead a battle tested solution based on any of the two libraries mentioned.

Comment: Using the mentioned libraries, is it possible create this configuration with java code instead of the xml file "persistence.xml"?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @KleberMota. Well, I never tested myself, but you could try something like the [following example](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-bootstrap-jpa-programmatically-without-the-persistence-xml-configuration-file/) from Vlad Mihalcea: it is Hibernate specific, but I think it could be of help. In any case, it is possible, at least override properties - although I am afraid not the provider itself - for instance, some frameworks such as Spring allows you to override some configuration properties: I will dig into it in the Spring specific use case.

Comment: Can you tell where to put the file "persistence.xml", if I decide to use this approach? I have tried put in the directory `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`  as suggested in the post, but it seems that is not working, since `@PersistenceUnit(name = "default") private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;` is getting null.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback again @KleberMota. Sorry for the late reply. Yes, it is the right location for `persistence.xml`. The problem is that in order to use `@PersistenceUnit` you need some type of DI mechanism such as Spring or CDI; on the contrary, you need to setup your `EntityManagerFactory` manually. I updated my answer trying to clarifying both things, I hope it helps.

Comment: I got the same issue when using `EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();` and I am using Maven like the answer suggests.

Comment: Thank you @KleberMota. It is strange indeed. Please, could you update your answer with the `persistence.xml` file that you are using? Did you included the required JPA provider libraries in your Maven dependencies?

Comment: that's what my project structure and pom.xml looks like right now: https://imgur.com/a/0Nn22V5

Comment: You are using the latest version of `eclipselink`. Please, can you remove the `javax.persistence` dependency in your `pom.xml` and include the [jakarta based one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/3.1.0) - in fact it should be already included as a dependency of `eclipselink`? Please, could you share your `persistence.xml` file as well? Probably you need to use the new XSD and property names in the Jakarta namespace. Please, see [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72860543/13942448) for reference.

Comment: Please, consider review [this post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/02/creating-a-simple-jakarta-persistence-application/) regarding the new Jakarta JPA persistence version: I was searching for information for trying helping you and I came across it, it is for hsqldb but I think it could be of help. Please,  note that you will need to update the imports in your code as well to, for instance, `jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory`. Note the `jakarta.persistence` package.

Comment: Yes, that worked, but now I am getting the error `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: opening db: '../data.db': Read-only file system` (the data.db file is located on the directory `src/main/resources` of my project, and the war file is deployed automatically by tomcat when I copy it in the directory `/var/lib/tomcat/webapps` (a directory `auth` is created with owner the user `tomcat` with the permissions: `drwxr-x---`)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @KleberMota. I am happy to hear that the issue was solved. Regarding the new problem, I think it could be motivated because you are probably trying to write to the SQLite database, but it is contained in the jar file, and I think it could be the reason for the read-only filesystem message. You usually embed the sqlite db file in a jar when, for instance, it stores some type of configuration that need only to read. If you require a database for writing I would recommend creating the db file in the server filesystem instead. In addition, it will allow you to reuse the

Comment: information stored in the database across application restarts.